# Creating dynamic URL link in ReactJS link using useParams hook

Tags: reactjs

I am creating an application that will show info about a post based on an id passed in through the URL parameters. For some reason, its not showing the page, instead showing the following error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

My code is as follows:

```js
// App.js --------- 
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/ideas" component={Ideas} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/ideas/:id" component={Idea} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

//Idea.js --------- 
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const Idea = () => {
    let { id } = useParams();

    return <div>Id: {id}</div>
};

export default Idea;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What version of `react-router` are you using?

Comment: the version I'm using is 6.0.2

Comment: Where is `Router` coming from? Are you sure, the problem if from `Idea` component while using `useParams` hook? If removing that, does the problem still persist?

Comment: Router is coming from react-router. If i comment the useParams() line, the application works fine

Comment: Looks like `react-router` is using `17.0.2` version of react as per [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/1becc3135c9330f21b8b3c8bd0b8926e6ad8670a/package.json#L51). Could you bump up the react version to use `17.0.2` too and see?

Comment: Im still getting the same error message

Comment: Can you set up a code sandbox replicating the issue? Heres a start: https://codesandbox.io/s/setting-up-dynamic-routes-react-router-dom-rzo37?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Updating my version of React still produced the same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you import `useParams` from react-router instead of react-router-dom, I think it should work. That is how I import mine and I have no issues.

`import { useParams } from 'react-router'`

Comment: I tried that and it just returned undefined from my useParams hook